# Setting double getElementById from document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a js function that sets the width of a progress bar, i have also recently added a new id see bellow

```
(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2").innerHTML) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1 + document.getElementById("results-suffix").innerHTML   ;
        }
    }
}());
```

I am calling this in HTML like

```
<div class="myProgress">
                        <div id="myBar" style="width:0">
                            <div id="demo"><span id="results-suffix"></span></div>
                            <!--<div id="demo"></div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
<span id="results-percentile-2"></span>%
```

Problem comes with the second ID `results-suffix` this works but now the first `results-percentile-2` dose not work, seems i can have one or the other, what am i doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: `innerHTML` would return a `string` and you're comparing it to a `Number`. Perhaps you'll want to `parseFloat()` first.

Comment: are you talking about results-percentile-2 or results-suffix ?

Comment: so parseFloat() for results-percentile-2 then innerHTM for results-suffix ?

Comment: Anytime you're performing an arithmetic operation on non-numeric data. See @Tuhin answer for example (using `Number`).

Comment: Yeah ive seen that and tried. it just returns NaN

Comment: add html for  results-percentile-2

Answer (score 0):

> Updated

```
(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        var width = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100)) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
                document.getElementById("results-percentile-2").innerHTML = width;
            }
        }
    }());
```

Comment: returns NaN, ill try it the other way around. UPDATE bot return NaN

Comment: add  HTML for "results-percentile-2"

Comment: No.. HTML tags of  results-percentile-2

Comment: `   if (width >= Number(document.getElementById(<span>"results-percentile-2"</span>).innerHTML)) {` ?

Comment: No dude.. In your HTML we cannot see the element with results-percentile-2 id